# The other side of the 'certifier' person

Tags: single-word-requests

So let's say I have person A certifying person B.
I call person A a 'certifier' - the one who certifies.
Is there a single word to describe a person B - the one who is being certified?

For simplicity the certification is a process where person A ensures person B possesses certain property.

Comment: I don't know if there's one word that covers all instances, but words like _trainee, student, apprentice, examinee_, and _candidate_ come to mind.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use "certifiable" to denote the person on the receiving end.  "Certifiable" is generally construed to mean "crazy".

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes, in Britain the terms *certify* and  *certified* are short forms for indicating that the necessary legal processes have been completed for compulsorily detaining a psychiatric patient. e.g. *Fred's been certified* or *steps are being taken to certify Mildred*.

Comment: @WS2, I heard in US it is used in the same way.

Comment: You obviously must use terms like "certified" when someone is, say, a Certified Public Accountant, but one should be careful to assure that the context is evident.   Don't use "Frank Jones is certified" as stand-alone statement, with no context to indicate "certified" in *what*.

Comment: @HotLicks That's an interesting one. We don't. I was an accountant (before I retired) so I know about this. If we are speaking generally we say *Is she a 'qualified' accountant ?*. But it is a bit more complicated. In the UK there are five professional accountancy institutes which have Royal Charter status. Only one of them has the word *certified* in its name. Rarely someone might say *he's a Certified Accountant* in order to distinguish him from a member of one of the other institutes. Otherwise the term Chartered Accountant is in wide use. Or 'he's CIPFA' or 'CIMA', initials as word.

Comment: @HotLicks My point was that we rarely used *certified* to indicate anything other than that a person is a compulsory psychiatric patient. Some years ago the government abandoned the need for people to get a doctor's certificate in order to claim state sickness benefit - and introduced a system of *self-certification* for minor ailments like flu. But the term caused much hilarity.

Comment: @WS2 - "Certified Public Accountant" (CPA) is the standard term in the US for an accountant who has passed the appropriate tests and has the appropriate license.  And it's common to hear "certified" when describing the qualifications of medical personnel.

Comment: @HotLicks I think there is a high correlation between US *certified* and UK *qualified*. *Is she a qualified doctor?* I realise it is complex because *qualified* has a quite separate meaning - such as in a *qualified acceptance*, meaning an acceptance with qualifications i.e. restrictions. Yes I know about CPAs. I have had dealings with many in my time, and we do speak a similar language - though there are still many differences in terminology across the Ocean.

Comment: @WS2 -  In my experience, CPAs speak Greek.

Comment: The certifying **party** or **entity** is what is used in legalese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Certificant" works, though some sources claim it isn't a "real" word.

Answer (score 0):

Candidate or applicant(not the best choice of words though)

Answer (score 0):

I think we call such persons-

### ACCREDITED.

### AUTHORISED

Or to use a single word noun--"LICENSEE"